# Flips and Flops in minimal model program

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Is there a concrete geometric intuition behind [**flips and flops**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip_(mathematics)) in context of minimal model program one should keep in mind? Wikipedia says that these can be considered as algebraic analoga of codimension-2 surgery operations. Surgery operations from topology have a precise geometric interpretation/picture. Are flips and flops coming also with a "geometric" picture? (ie is there "something" in the structure what is literally "flipped" under this operations; maybe in the configuration of the involved divisors?)

Formally, for a morphism $f: X \to Y$ of $k$-schemes with well defined $K_X$ canonical bundle of $X$ there is naturally given the induced map

$f^+: \text{Proj}(\bigoplus_m f_*(\mathcal{O}_X(mK))) \to Y$

and by definition $f^+$ is called **flip** of $f$ if $-K$ relatively amply, and **flop** if $K$ is trivial.

So it's plausible to ask if there is any geometric "justification" (if we specialize to varieties over field $k= \mathbb{C}$) for these names **flip** and **flop** or is the reason really just to distinguish between these two "atomic" operations depending on formal condition on the canonical divisor $K$?

A naive idea: if we think about about resolution procedure of a surface (over $\mathbb{C}$ to assure that it's possible), then there is no unique "canonical" sequence of blowing ups at points leading to smooth model. So maybe (I not know) to name "flip" may have something to do with "flipping" between different intermediate blowups of the resolution in a "controlled" way?

Comment: Personally, I have the threefold MMP in mind when I'm thinking about flips/flops. In this case, a flip usually refers to replacing a K-negative extremal curve with a K-positive curve, and a flop is a surgery that replaces a K-trivial curve with another K-trivial curve. The wikipedia definition seems to generalize this, although it is unclear to me if it is using standard terminology. Typically I refer to Kollár-Mori for these definitions.